# Why do I get 'object has no 'xxx' property' on a non-required field

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to do a SOAP request but PHP Soapclient says I have to enter a field. The field does not seem to be required by the WSDL. I've been able to work around this by adding all the fields to the request, but this is not sufficient anymore.

I've tested with SoapUI, which does not return this error. Also $client->__getLastRequest() returns null, so I believe PHP is hanging on wsdl validation.

Please also look at the WSDL in the code.

```
<?php
$wsdl = 'http://api.untill.com:3063/wsdl/ITPAPIPOS';
$options = [
    'exceptions' => true,
    'trace' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
];

$client = new Soapclient($wsdl, $options);

$client->UpdateClients([
    'UserName' => 'user',
    'Password' => 'name',
    'Clients' => [
        [
             'Id' => 1,
             'Number' => 3,
             'Name' => 'John',
        ]
     ],
    'Extra' => []
]);
```

SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Country' property